# Why foo is not nil anymore - or function within function

Tags: ruby

Why in below code snippet foo replaces its definition?

```
def foo
  def foo
    1
  end
end
```

---

for the first time `foo` is nil

```
foo
=> nil

foo.foo
=> 1
```

Now if I call `foo` again:

```
foo
=> 1
```

As you can see `foo` is not nil anymore. Can some one explain this to me? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def foo
  p "about to redef foo"
  def foo
    1
  end
end
```

```
foo
"about to redef foo"
=> nil
foo
=> 1
```

Also, when you call `foo.foo`, it seems like you’re trying to access the inner `foo` method, but it doesn’t work that way. Your `foo` method is actually defined on `Object`, so you’re actually calling `1.foo`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this effect, try

```
def foo
  foo = proc {
    1
  }
end
```

Since `def` methods do not create a new `self`. Every method is bound
to `self`, which is `main` in this case, an Object.new which is
instantiated for every file loaded by the ruby interpreter. Inside a
class, `self` is the class, and you get instance methods.

Comment: The assignment is not required.

Comment: He wants foo within another namespace, but yes, the function just return a block.

Answer (score 1):

Method definitions are parsed when read, but are not executed until called. When you do the first `foo`, the outermost `foo` is executed, which defines `Object#foo` as

```
def foo
  1
end
```

and returns `nil` as the return value of an operation that defined the method. From then on, when you call `foo`, the newly defined `foo` is executed, returning

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

When your first call `foo` it returns method `foo` and when you call again `foo` it returns 1.
Read [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Actually it returns nil the first time, b/c Ruby doesn't support 1st class methods (in this sense at least). So no method object is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Nested method definitions in ruby are confusing.

They are actually redefinitions!

What happens is that both definitions apply to the outmost context. That is both definitions define the same(!) method foo. Though the outer definition is interpreted when the file is read, while the inner definition is only interpreted when the outer method is called for the first time. It will then replace the initial definition.

Given this code

```
def foo
  def foo
    1
  end
end
```

Let's walk through this:

1. when loading your file a global method `foo` is defined with the body `def foo; 1; end`.
2. when you call `foo()` this global method is executed and **redefines the global method** `foo` with the body `1`, and returns `nil` since defining a method has no return value.
3. when you call `foo().foo()` the global method is executed and returns `1`, on which the global method is executed again, returning `1` again.

Confusing here are two things, a) that nested method definition both apply to the same outer scope and b) that a global method can be called on any object.

Here's another example to demonstrate how nested definitions are actually redefinitions.

```
class A
  def m(arg=nil)
    def m; 42; end if arg
    23
  end
end
```

here's what happens

```
a = A.new
a.m # => 23
a.m # => 23
a.m(:magic) # => 23
a.m # => 42
a.m # => 42
```

as you can see, the nested definition is actually a redefinition.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always thought it very strange that it defines inner `def` on the class. I would think it more sensible to define it on the singleton. e.g. equivalent to `def self.foo`, since it is being called at the instance level and not the class level.

Either that, or it could only be callable from the method it is defined in --though that might not be as useful since we have lambdas.

One thing is for certain though, you will almost never see this in practice.